# Play/scala app for Heroku stopped running

Tags: scala, ssl, heroku, playframework

All of a sudden facing this issue while running my heroku app locally, my Play/Scala app isn't working. Seeing this error which may be causing cannot load SSL context:

```
22:27:05 web.1   |  Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: system properties: path has type OBJECT rather than STRING
```

Procfile:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dhttps.port=${PORT} -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.keyStore.path=conf/generated.keystore
```

I get the same error on remote as well. If I run the app locally without Heroku, I don't see any issue (sbt -Dhttps.port=$1 -Dhttp.port=disabled ~run). Its not clear what config property it is referring to. Play version 2.5.4.

Full log:

```
$ heroku local web
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
22:26:38 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:26:38,177 [debug] p.a.l.c.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
22:26:39 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:26:39,289 [debug] p.a.d.s.DefaultSlickApi - Created Slick database config for key admin.
22:26:40 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:26:40,049 [debug] p.a.d.s.DefaultSlickApi - Created Slick database config for key default.
22:26:40 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:26:40,276 [info] play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
22:26:40 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:26:40,394 [info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTPS on /0.0.0.0:5000
22:27:05 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:27:05,481 [error] p.c.s.NettyServer - cannot load SSL context
22:27:05 web.1   |  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
22:27:05 web.1   |      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createScalaSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:96)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:32)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at play.core.server.NettyServer.liftedTree1$1(NettyServer.scala:91)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at play.core.server.NettyServer.play$core$server$NettyServer$$sslEngineProvider$lzycompute(NettyServer.scala:90)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at play.core.server.NettyServer.play$core$server$NettyServer$$sslEngineProvider(NettyServer.scala:89)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$channelSink$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:158)
22:27:05 web.1   |  Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: system properties: path has type OBJECT rather than STRING
22:27:05 web.1   |      at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:159)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:170)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:184)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:189)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:246)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:34)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.<init>(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:24)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
22:27:05 web.1   |      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
22:27:05 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:27:05,531 [debug] application - Client Error: code: 400, msg: text is empty
22:27:05 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:27:05,531 [debug] application - Request: GET /bad-request
22:27:05 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:27:05,533 [debug] application -     content-type: None
22:27:05 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:27:05,533 [debug] application -     headers: ArrayBuffer()
22:27:05 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:27:05,533 [debug] application - Request: GET /bad-request
22:27:05 web.1   |  2017-08-17 22:27:05,534 [debug] application -     query string: 

$ find . -type f -name "*.keystore"
./conf/generated.keystore
./target/scala-2.11/classes/generated.keystore
./target/universal/stage/conf/generated.keystore
$
```

Answer (score 0):

After following the post [How to configure Play! 2.4.2 HTTPS keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744167/how-to-configure-play-2-4-2-https-keystore), I changed Procfile to

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dhttps.port=${PORT} -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.keyStore=conf/generated.keystore
```

and it went past this error. That is, I removed ".path" from https.keyStore variable.

Comment: you don't need to implement HTTPS on Heroku unless you're using Private Spaces. Heroku does HTTPS for you (terminating at the router) so your app can safely use HTTP.