# Playframework in production (http & https) - error

Tags: ssl, playframework

Do you have any idea what is going on? Is the path on conf file? How can I fix to find this file on production mode?

On dev mode the project is working without problems. The idea is to run on production mode on the server. But when I generate in production mode -> sbt dist and execute to run I got the follow errors:

```
    [error] p.c.s.NettyServer - cannot load SSL context
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createScalaSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:96)
        at play.core.server.ssl.ServerSSLEngine$.createSSLEngineProvider(ServerSSLEngine.scala:32)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.liftedTree1$1(NettyServer.scala:91)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.play$core$server$NettyServer$$sslEngineProvider$lzycompute(NettyServer.scala:90)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer.play$core$server$NettyServer$$sslEngineProvider(NettyServer.scala:89)
        at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$channelSink$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:158)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\temp\test\webportal-1.0-SNAPSHOT\bin\conf\generated.keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at play.core.server.ssl.FakeKeyStore$.keyManagerFactory(FakeKeyStore.scala:72)
        at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:61)
        at play.core.server.ssl.DefaultSSLEngineProvider.<init>(DefaultSSLEngineProvider.scala:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

Comment: possibly already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744167/how-to-configure-play-2-4-2-https-keystore

Comment: Does the above link help you or not?